# Check if object can be fetched by garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection

is there a way to check if an object can be fetched by the garbage collector?

Somewhere in my code I've got a reference to an object:

```
MyObject mo = myObject;
```

Then, via Eclipse Debugger, I get the objects memory location. Afterwards, I set the reference null:

```
mo = null;
```

Is there any way to check if the previously referenced object is now suitable for garbage collection or if there's somewhere another reference to it?

Thanks a lot,

Stefan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot do this at runtime with an arbitrary object, and in fact it's not fully possible to do this deterministically.  However, there are two options that may be suitable depending on your needs:

1. Take a heap dump after you set the reference to `null`, and then load it up in a heap analyzer tool such as [jhat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) or a profiler that supports this.  These tools should let you traverse the path from the GC roots and thus check if your object is still reachable or not.
2. Wrap the object in a [PhantomReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) with a given `ReferenceQueue`.  When the reference is enqueued, you know that the object has been garbage collected.  (Unfortunately, if the reference is unqueued it could be because the object is still reachable, or it could be because the GC just hasn't inspected the object yet.  As with all GC-related questions, garbage collection is not a deterministic process!)

On the whole though, I agree that the best option is to be *aware* of memory leak issues and design your application to avoid them.  If you do have a memory leak it should be obvious enough, and you can then focus your energies on finding the problem (again by dumping and analysing the heap for objects that are incorrectly reachable).

The steps above are relatively time-consuming, and shouldn't be something that you do after every change just to reassure yourself, but rather are tools you'd use to investigate a *specific* problem.

Comment: it's a huuuuuuuuuuuuuge application, where we experienced memory problems. one optimization should now lead to improvement, but not as much as we expected. therefore we would like to know if specific objects are garbage collected. thanks for your reply, i'll try it out!

Comment: Correct you will get a pure garbage :D

Answer (score 1):

No. The only thing to do is to be careful and keep in mind that memory leaks can exist in Java when writing your application.

The only you can do, is to use tools to try to find where memory leaks come from when you noticed such a problem. I would strongly recommend [Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) for this purpose.

Comment: thanks for your reply! of course being careful is the most important thing, but sometimes it's just not enough or possible (see answer to andrzey doyle)