# Can unreferenced objects still run if the garbage collector hasn't deleted them?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

If an object is waiting to be garbage collected, but contains a thread that was running when the last reference to the object was changed, will that thread still run and will the code still execute? So could you potentially have a bunch of ghost objects that should be deleted, but are having an effect on your code? How do you prevent this? Is there a way for an object to tell if it is waiting to be collected?

Comment: Thread objects dont require to be referred to be alive. They have to die to become eligible for gc.

Comment: "How do you prevent this" --> do not run threads from within them; make them return a `Callable` or `Runnable` which you schedule for execution yourself in an `ExecutorService` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A thread wont be garbage collected until it has finished, so if your threads never finish, they will not be available for garbage collection. As noted by fge in the comments, often times the thread will have reference to the enclosing object, which will of course prevent the thread from being garbage collected.

As for knowing if an object is on its way to be collected, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223956/check-if-object-can-be-fetched-by-garbage-collector?rq=1) answer has some nice details on what you can(and can't) do.

Other than that, you can suggest the jvm to run garbage collection with system.gc(), but there is no guarantee the jvm will run the garbage collector.

Comment: It is also more than likely that the thread in question will have a reference to the enclosing object instance, so in fact the object is _not_ elected for gc anyway...

Answer (score 0):

The thread will run until finishes, no matter if the object which maybe created the thread and holds a reference to it is still alive, is currently accessible or is eligible for garbage collection.

If you want a thread to be tied to the lifetime of an object, you perhaps should implement `java.lang.AutoCloseable`, and ask the thread to terminate itself in `close()`.