# Assigning null to an object with a running method

Tags: java

I have a method, `disconnectUser()` which among other things, assigns `null` to an object `userSession` at the end of execution. However, a hypothetical arose as I was coming up with the logic, where say `userSession` has a running method and it is assigned a null reference while it is still executing; how does the JVM deal with such a situation?

FWIW here are some code snippets for context:

---

```
public class A {
    UserSession userSession;

    /* Skipped irrelevant code
    *-------------------------------
    */

    private void disconnectUser(){
      //Runs an endless while-loop (it's for demonstration's sake)
      userSession.runEndlessLoop();

      userSession = null;
    }
}
```

ADDENDUM:

Here's the implementation for `runEndlessLoop`

```
public void runEndlessLoop(){
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> while(true){});
}
```

Comment: Yea sounds like a memory leak waiting to happen...

Comment: And anyhow if you run an endless loop you will never execute the line that assigns null to usersession, andvif it wasn't endless you would no longer be in a method in usersession by the time you assign null to the reference

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt good point (head-desk), let me fix that up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`userSession` is a reference to an object. You "assign" `null` to this reference, not to an object. So you are changing this reference. It doesn't change the object `userSession` formerly referenced / pointed to.

Also see: [Can unreferenced objects still run if the garbage collector hasn't deleted them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002857/can-unreferenced-objects-still-run-if-the-garbage-collector-hasnt-deleted-them)

Let me try to add this: If the method of this object is running in the same thread as the rest of your program, the reference would be changed **after** this method finishes, so the problem doesn't even come up.
If, in contrast, this object acts in a different thread, well... i just tested it:

```
public class UnreferencedTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UnreferencedTest u = new UnreferencedTest();
        u.createObject();
    }

    private void createObject() {

        Unreferenced obj = new Unreferenced();
        Thread t = new Thread(obj);//create new thread
        t.start();
        obj = null;     //remove only reference to object
        System.gc();    //ask GC to clean up

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000); //wait a bit longer than other thread
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class Unreferenced implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                areYouStillHere();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void areYouStillHere() {
            System.out.println("I'm still here!");
        }
    }

}
```

... and even "asked" the GC to clean up unreferenced objects. (no guarantee it does!) It's only waiting for 5 seconds, but still runs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: In other words, the objects continues execution in the background and doesn't get garbage collected until it's done?

Comment: @Garikai I added some explanation and sample code to play around with!

Comment: That's  a very informative test case you came up with there

Comment: Thank you, but my code was **wrong**! I changed it to actually start a new thread (forgot to do that)... now the object still seems to do it's work.