# Ways to check at runtime whether an object has been garbage collected in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Ways to check *at runtime* whether an object has been garbage collected in Java?

Comment: Already answered.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223956/check-if-object-can-be-fetched-by-garbage-collector

Comment: Ankit:
String one = "first";
one = "second";
By just reading the ideas in the page you link to, how would we check whether or not "first" got GC'd?